# general questions about versions of entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Well, I would like to clear some doubts that I have about the different versions of entity.

If I go to Microsoft, to the download center, I can get the entity framework 4.1 update 1 that I can install in my computer.

However, in the nuget.org website, I can download 4.3.1. This does not have an installer like the 4.1 that I can download from Microsoft. Is una independant version or I need to install the 4.1 first?

How I have not an installer of the 4.3.1 version, if I want to use the application that use this version in other computer, how can I do it? with a local copy of the dll is enough?

I ask this because in one project first I installed EF 4.1 update 1 and later I install through the packages manager of VS2010 the EF 4.5 version that use the dll 4.4. I do a local copy in my folder application, but when I try to run the application in other computer it says me that I try to use types that not exists. If I install the EF 4.1 update 1 in the computer, the the application works fine.

I would like to avoid the need of installing EF 4.1 in each computer in which I want to run the application, because I would like to have a portable application, so I only would like to install .NET 4.0 and the other aditional components do a local copy.

Also, I try to use a local copy of many entityframework.dll in my application, but I only see one file. Is it possible to have in as local copy in the main folder of my application many versions of the same dll?

Comment: As far as I know after version 4.1 they move the package to nuget and there are no executable installers anymore. If you want to install them you need to use nuget packege manager

Comment: If you go to the NuGet website, you can download version 6. Although, [5 is the most recent stable version](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/5.0.0).

Comment: Well, If I install the libraries through nuget, How Can I use this in other computers? How can I install the needed libraries? Because I do a local copy, but in the other computer says me that I don't have some requiered types.

Comment: it should be fine to just use a copy of the nuget package files on other computers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF releases and versioning is a bit of a mess :-)

MS guys were the first to admit it and that’s why they rationalize how they were naming and distributing their releases.

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574253) to see the whole EF version history and have a look at this particular [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/08/09/ef-releases-amp-versioning-call-for-feedback.aspx) on ADO .Net Blog where they were calling for feedback about versioning issues. That’s quite interesting.

Now that you have a clear view of EF releases and versioning, let’s talk about your own releasing issue!

Basically, as soon as the right .Net framework is installed on the target machine (i.e.: where you want to install your app), it’ up to your application installation package to provide with every other library your app needs to work properly!

In VisualStudio, right-click on your application project and select “publish”, this should help you to build the proper installation package.

Hope this helps!